# Как в asyncData axios сделать вывод ошибок?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

Как в asyncData выводить код ошибки, который идет с сервера или сообщения + другие ошибки catch?

```
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
      const query = await $axios
        .$get(`/api/v1/shop/1/banners`)
        .then((response) => {
          return response
        })
      return {
        banners: query.banners,
        currentPage: query.current_page,
        lastPage: query.last_page,
        perPage: query.per_page,
      }
  },
  data() {
    return {
  }
```

так что-то не работает

данные с сервера идут вот так

```
{"error":false,"current_page":1,"last_page":1,"per_page":16,"banners":[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
 const query = await $axios
            .$get(`/api/v1/shop/1/banners`)
            .then((response) => {
              return response
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
             // действия, которые нужно совершить при ошибке,например, вернуть ее
            })
```